Unable to build my SPfx, error @microsoft/sharepoint Command failed with exit code 1: npm install
I want to build an SPFX, i did the following steps:-
1)Inside c: i created a folder name SPFx
2)inside node.js i have this :-

3)I run this command:-
yo @microsoft/sharepoint


but i got this error:-

Here is the logs

2001 http fetch GET 200
https://registry.npmjs.org/normalize-package-data 145ms (cache
revalidated) 2002 http fetch GET 200
https://registry.npmjs.org/any-promise 150ms (cache revalidated) 2003
http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/detect-indent 153ms
(cache revalidated) 2004 http fetch GET 200
https://registry.npmjs.org/sort-keys 155ms (cache revalidated) 2005
http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/p-reflect 154ms (cache
revalidated) 2006 http fetch GET 200
https://registry.npmjs.org/@pnpm%2fwrite-project-manifest 536ms (cache
revalidated) 2007 http fetch GET 200
https://registry.npmjs.org/read-yaml-file 614ms (cache revalidated)
2008 timing idealTree:node_modules/@pnpm/link-bins Completed in 627ms
2009 timing idealTree:node_modules/@pnpm/error Completed in 0ms 2010
silly placeDep ROOT fast-glob@3.3.2 OK for: @pnpm/package-bins@4.1.0
want: ^3.2.4 2011 silly fetch manifest @nodelib/fs.stat@^2.0.2 2012
silly fetch manifest @nodelib/fs.walk@^1.2.3 2013 silly fetch manifest
glob-parent@^5.1.2 2014 silly fetch manifest merge2@^1.3.0 2015 http
fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@nodelib%2ffs.stat 268ms
(cache revalidated) 2016 http fetch GET 200
https://registry.npmjs.org/@nodelib%2ffs.walk 278ms (cache
revalidated) 2017 timing idealTree:node_modules/@pnpm/package-bins
Completed in 281ms 2018 timing
idealTree:node_modules/@pnpm/read-modules-dir Completed in 0ms 212225
info run es5-ext@0.10.64 postinstall node_modules/es5-ext node -e
"try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}" || exit 0 12226 info run
node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall node_modules/node-sass node
scripts/build.js 12227 info run es5-ext@0.10.64 postinstall { code: 0,
signal: null } 12228 timing build:run:postinstall:node_modules/es5-ext
Completed in 215ms 12229 info run node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall { code:
1, signal: null } 12230 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed
in 23161ms 12231 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
12232 timing command:install Completed in 160278ms 12233 verbose stack
Error: command failed 12233 verbose stack at ChildProcess.
(C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.13.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
12233 verbose stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28) 12233
verbose stack at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
12233 verbose stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
(node:internal/child_process:301:5) 12234 verbose pkgid
node-sass@4.14.1 12235 verbose cwd c:\SPFX 12236 verbose Windows_NT
10.0.22631 12237 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
"install" 12238 verbose node v16.13.1 12239 verbose npm v8.1.2 12240
error code 1 12241 error path c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-sass 12242
error command failed 12243 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
/d /s /c node scripts/build.js 12244 error Building: C:\Program
Files\nodejs\node.exe c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags=
--libsass_library= 12245 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok 12245 error gyp verb cli [ 12245 error gyp verb cli 'C:\Program
Files\nodejs\node.exe', 12245 error gyp verb cli
'c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js', 12245 error gyp
verb cli 'rebuild', 12245 error gyp verb cli '--verbose', 12245 error
gyp verb cli '--libsass_ext=', 12245 error gyp verb cli
'--libsass_cflags=', 12245 error gyp verb cli '--libsass_ldflags=',
12245 error gyp verb cli '--libsass_library=' 12245 error gyp verb cli
] 12245 error gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0 12245 error gyp info using
node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64 12245 error gyp verb command rebuild []
12245 error gyp verb command clean [] 12245 error gyp verb clean
removing "build" directory 12245 error gyp verb command configure []
12245 error gyp verb check python checking for Python executable
"python2" in the PATH 12245 error gyp verb whichfailed Error: not
found: python2 12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at getNotFoundError
(c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at F
(c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at E
(c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at
c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16 12245
error gyp verbwhichfailed at c:\SPFX\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at
c:\SPFX\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5 12245 error gyp
verbwhichfailed at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) 12245
error gyp verbwhichfailed python2 Error: not found: python2 12245
error gyp verbwhichfailed at getNotFoundError
(c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at F
(c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at E
(c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at
c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16 12245
error gyp verbwhichfailed at c:\SPFX\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at
c:\SPFX\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5 12245 error gyp
verbwhichfailed at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) { 12245
error gyp verbwhichfailed code: 'ENOENT' 12245 error gyp
verbwhichfailed } 12245 error gyp verb check python checking for
Python executable "python" in the PATH 12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed
Error: not found: python 12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at
getNotFoundError
(c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at F
(c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at E
(c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at
c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16 12245
error gyp verbwhichfailed at c:\SPFX\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at
c:\SPFX\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5 12245 error gyp
verbwhichfailed at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) 12245
error gyp verbwhichfailed python Error: not found: python 12245 error
gyp verbwhichfailed at getNotFoundError
(c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at F
(c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at E
(c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at
c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16 12245
error gyp verbwhichfailed at c:\SPFX\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
12245 error gyp verbwhichfailed at
c:\SPFX\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5 12245 error gyp
verbwhichfailed at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) { 12245
error gyp verbwhichfailed code: 'ENOENT' 12245 error gyp verb``` which
failed } `` 12245 error gyp verb could not find "python". checking
python launcher 12245 error gyp verb could not find "python". guessing
location 12245 error gyp verb ensuring that file exists:
C:\Python27\python.exe 12245 error gyp ERR! configure error 12245
error gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you
can set the PYTHON env variable. 12245 error gyp ERR! stack at
PythonFinder.failNoPython
(c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19) 12245 error
gyp ERR! stack at PythonFinder.
(c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16) 12245 error
gyp ERR! stack at callback
(c:\SPFX\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:306:20) 12245 error gyp
ERR! stack at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) 12245 error
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22631 12245 error gyp ERR! command
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
"c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose"
"--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags="
"--libsass_library=" 12245 error gyp ERR! cwd
c:\SPFX\node_modules\node-sass 12245 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
12245 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0 12245 error gyp ERR! not ok
12245 error Build failed with error code: 1 12246 verbose exit 1

then i run npm install, but i got this error:-

any advice?

Based on your screenshot information, I found this message:

Can't find Python executable "python",you can set the PYTHON env
variable.

Are you using python, but you don't set python environment variables? You can refer to this article to set it up first, and then see if the problem persists.
Error: Can't Find Python Executable Python, You Can Set the PYTHON Env Variable

It's seems you're trying to run SPFx v1.13.0 on node v.16.13.1 - this won't work, as SPFx v1.13.0 only supports node version v12 and v14.
Please have a look at the SPFx compatibility list below.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility
